# Arbitrary and non sense string inside a code block

Tags: c#

This is something , i don't understand , if i put any arbitrary string inside a code block, it will throw some compile time error but if i put something like below , it will not.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 5;

       ghfhfghfghfghfhfghfhfghfghfghfhfghfghfghghttp://www.google.com
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

any idea why this is happening? I just found it accidentally , not sure why , may be i am missing something.

Comment: It's a Label see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a Label.

Look at the `:` at the end.

If you remove the `:` in the end. It won't compile

[goto and label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`ghfhfghfghfghfhfghfhfghfghfghfhfghfghfghghttp:` is a label, because it's followed by `:`.

You can then use it with [`goto` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 5;

    ghfhfghfghfghfhfghfhfghfghfghfhfghfghfghghttp://www.google.com
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();

    goto ghfhfghfghfghfhfghfhfghfghfghfhfghfghfghghttp;
}
```

Comment: @mdenton8 Why? reason?

Comment: @mdenton8 - never use `goto` in school projects. In real code use it when required (which will indeed be very rare).

Comment: Because 1) you don't need it. Technically ever. 2) It creates downright unreadable code. --It's an age-old debate and even back in the 1960s legendary computer scientist Edsger Dijkstra vehemently opposed `goto`, and was calling the fight against `goto` "old news." That being said, many legendary computer scientists will forgive its use when it's used to break out of nested loops without the use of an extra boolean variable.